Universal Turing Machine
I have two exercises to universal TMs.
A deterministic UTM M' that simulates a TM M with runtime T simulates it in O(T*log(T)).
Now I have to construct a nondeterministic UTM M' that works in Time O(T*log(T)) for a TM M that works in O(T) and I have to construct a UTM M' that works in space O(S) for a TM M that works in O(S) space.
But yet I don't have any idea how I could do this.
Do you have any hints?
